# How Azure Logic app can long runs for days?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have external application as questionnaire and this application can be accessed by users' cellphone, table & web. This questionnaire quite heavy load, 128K/day.

For capturing data that come from those devices, I put `Logic app`. It looks good and works well but `Logic app` has [limit duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#timeout-duration), 120 seconds. I thought `logic app` can solve my design but the limitation restricts my initial idea. So,

1. How do I overcome this limitation ?
2. Do I need add additional services as a listener from questionnaire application as data feeding to `Logic app` ?
3. Could the limitation be modified for 30 days ?

[image]

Comment: What does the logic app actually do? What step is taking such a long time?

Comment: When say it’s limited to 120 seconds, that’s not entirely correct. Certain HTTP scenarios are limited to that period. Technically, a LogicApp can run for days. Can you show us the specific error? Do you need to supply a synchronous response to the calling application?

Comment: @PeterBons, Logic app will do as listener if questionnaire online has post input and trigger logic app to receive value from it. There is already API that responses 'When a response is submitted'

Comment: @skin, this is the error in 'Parse JSON', `
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'Required property 'content' expects a value but got null. Path ''.'`.

Comment: @skin, I don't understand with a synchronous (or asynchronous ?) response, you mentioned above and what the effect of this.

Comment: Ok, firstly, you need to show us where in your app that error occurs.  i.e. provide a screenshot.  Secondly, do you need to do some processing and then send a response back to the caller with some data (synchronous) or is it set and forget, meaning, does the calling application require a specific response with data?  If not, that's asynchronous.